# Inherit Sensio Generator Bundle

Tags: symfony

I see http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/index.html

if i make my override template in app/Resources/SensioGeneratorBundle/skeleton/...

it's ok with twig tag

`{% extends 'skeleton/bundle/Bundle.php.twig' %}`

and overriding block

but if i create my own GeneratorBundle "inherit" SensioGeneratorBundle with

`public function getParent()
    {
        return 'SensioGeneratorBundle';
    }`

and put my override skeleton template in BUNDLE_PATH/Resources/SensioGeneratorBundle/skeleton like the documentation say it's does'nt work

i need to create my own bundle for override command

i'll do mix both ? "inherit" bundle for override command and override template in app/Resources

or i can juste "inherit" bundle and override command and skeleton template in bundle ?

thx for replies

**EDIT**

i've open a issue in SensioGeneratorBundle :

https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/issues/233

The GeneratorBundleCommand dont take my inherit bundle in parameter in method getGenerator()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the skeleton folder can't be overriding like other overriding template described here :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html

tell me if i'm wrong

and the BUNDLE_PATH described in :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/index.html

corresponding to any bundle, i thought that corresponding to my inherit sensio generator bundle.

so i put my skeleton in APP_PATH

EDIT : a pull request is open for this feature : https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/pull/235

Answer (score -1):

Please read [Symfony 2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html). After override getParent() by this you can replace commands. Remember to put child bundle after parent bundle in AppKernel

Skeleton templates cannot be overriden by classic bundle inheritance. Each bundle can provide own controller and doctrine templates. To override global skeleton (like bundle) you have to put it in app/Resources.

To overrite: Resources/SensioGeneratorBundle/template_name.twig

To extend: Resources/SesnsioGeneratorBundle/skeleton/template_name.twig

Comment: thx for reply 
Yes i do ! my directories are :
src/Vendor/Bundle/GeneratorBundle/Resources/skeleton/...
but does'nt work ! 

for example : 
`
{# src/Vendor/Bundle/GeneratorBundle/Resources/skeleton/bundle/Bundle.php.twig #}
{% extends 'skeleton/bundle/Bundle.php.twig' %}

{% block use_statements %}
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel as HttpKernel;
{% endblock use_statements %}

{% block class_definition %}
class {{ bundle }} extends HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle
{% endblock class_definition %}
`

Comment: When you inherit by getParent() symfony at first trying to find resource in app (Resource/ChildBundleName), next on children bundle, next on parent bundle. Try put your resources into app/GeneratorBundle/...

Comment: If i put my resources into app/Resources/SensioGeneratorBundle that's work like i say in my first comment, may be i'll be mix both inherit bundle for override command and override skeleton in app/Resources but i wanna override skeleton in bundle too

Comment: As I sad in comment. Please if you have you bundle GeneratorBundle with getParent() done, put your overriden skeletons into app/Resources/NewBundleName/skeleton

Comment: Thx zulus, i know will be work like that ! but i wish my override skeletons in my bundle not in app/Resources/MyBundle, it's possible u think ? meanwhile i put my override skeletons resouces in app/Resouces folder

Comment: The documentation say : 

You can define custom skeleton templates by creating the same directory and file structure in APP_PATH/Resources/SensioGeneratorBundle/skeleton or BUNDLE_PATH/Resources/SensioGeneratorBundle/skeleton if you want to extend the generator bundle (to be able to share your templates for instance in several projects).

Comment: But it's does'nt work !! i've put my override skeletons resources in MyBundle/Resources/SensioGeneratorBundle/skeleton ! but does'nt work its my problem

Comment: I've checked source code. You cannot override Bundle template by GeneratorBundleInherit. This method is only for CRUD etc.. Each bundle can provide own skeleton templates. After bundle inherit (for commands), you still can use app/Resources/Sensio... but be aware, your child bundle have to be registered after SensioGeneratorBundle

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40370/discussion-between-zulus-and-l0rd59)